# Does visiting Cyprus via a multiple-entry Schengen visa count towards the maximum length of stay of the visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, multiple-entry, 90-180-visa-rules, cyprus

A person obtained a multiple-entry Schengen visa with a duration of stay of 90 days and a validity of a year.

If this person stays in the Schengen zone 70 days and then goes on vacation in Cyprus for 30 days, will the person be allowed back into the Schengen zone for the remaining 20 days, or will these 30 days in Cyprus count towards the duration of stay limit of the Schengen visa and make the visa expired?

Comment: Cyprus is not part of Schengen https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/e-library/docs/schengen_brochure/schengen_brochure_dr3111126_en.pdf

Comment: @Traveller but holders of Schengen visas can use those visas to enter Cyprus, which is why this question is interesting. Pingo: you should be aware that the 90-day limit applies to each 180-day period, not to the whole 1-year period of the visa's validity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stays in Cyprus do **not** count towards the Schengen clock. It may have the same visa policy, but it's still a different country from Schengen, and you'll be stamped in and out of there separately.

Comment: Do you perhaps know, if for such a person a return ticket is required upon arrival?

Comment: @pingo The TIMATIC database used by airlines does say "Visitors not holding return/onward tickets could be refused entry" (except for EU/Schengen citizens). So to be safe, book a fully refundable throwaway ticket that you can cancel after entering Cyprus. However, it's unlikely Cypriot police will actually check it.

Comment: thanks a lot for the information even though it is a bit out of the scope. Might I ask how I can check the TIMATIC database myself in the future?

Comment: @pingo Here, for example http://cms.olympicair.com/timatic/webdocsI/spdbmainv.html